# Rails 3.1 - force SCSS variable value refresh?

Tags: css, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass

I've set up a set of [object].css.scss styles in my assets/stylesheets directory to correspond with the different views in my application.  Every sheet includes a set of global style variable values in the first line:

```
@import "branding.css.scss";
```

And then accesses the variable values when needed ($primaryColor, $secondaryColor, etc) throughout the library.

It's beautifully dry, but unfortunately Rails doesn't refresh the object stylesheets when I make a change to the variable values in the _branding.css.scss file.  I have to go and touch each file before the SCSS recompiles the object style library with the updated variable value.

This is a minor gripe but it's disruptive to the workflow, especially when I keep clearing the browser cache trying to fix it :/

Is there a better way to organize variables?

Is there any way to force the refresh?

Comment: The Rails team disregarded the Sass conventions that have developed over the years and tried to support the syntax blandly while combining it with Sprockets (which is designed to work with "dumb" CSS). I would love to hear a suggestion on how to change the behavior of Sprockets to the behavior of Sass auto-compilation (on request if any files changed, caching in a tmp directory), but I don't think we're going to find one. These Asset Pipeline problems will probably hold 3.1 in RC for at least a couple more weeks.

Answer (score 3):

I've been putting variables and mixins into an `includes.css.scss` file and importing them into each stylesheet that requires them.  To make Rails recompile when the includes file is changed you need to use the `depend_on` directive in application.js.  For example:

**application.css**:

```
/*
   *= depend_on includes
   *= require_self
   *= require stylesheet
*/
```

**includes.css.scss**:

```
$bg-color: #999;
```

**stylesheet.css.scss**:

```
@import "includes.css.scss";

body { background: $bg-color; }
```

Comment: Do you mean application.css?  I tried this and it didn't force the refresh.  I'm developing on Win7 because I'm a masochist, maybe that's why.

Comment: Yes I did, sorry about that!  I haven't noticed any problems with but maybe try `*= require includes` instead of `*= depend_on includes` and see if that works?  It may also be worth checking out the Sprockets docs: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed very annoying...

I don't have a complete solution, but one thing I've found is that all you need to do is touch 'application.css.scss' to get it recompile everything.

I've started using guard-compass and guard-livereload recently, but it has the same problem in 3.1. Maybe someone cleverer than me could fix it so that it touches 'application.css.scss' as well?